# How to load the ScrollView subViews in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am using scrollview in my app.I have changed UIScrollview to UICollectionView due to performance issues.We are displaying 19types feeds in scrollview,with input as objects and output as UIView.

While implementing this in UICollectionViewCell the design I am getting is not desirable. So my question to you is 
how to implement each main subview(which contains all the design) in the scrollview is changed UICollectionViewCell subview i.e subviews displaying in the collectionViewCell is displaying like subview of the scrollView without disturbing design.

Comment: By disabling the collection view scroll and set UIScrollView content size as collection view frame you can achieve this.

Comment: If array contains 10 objects, then 10 feeds are generating(each collection view cell have a feed). every collectionview cell have a each subview. then how can we disable the collection view scroll.

Comment: can you post the snap of collection view ?